# How do I use two-way data-binding and not one-to-one convertation?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a TextBox that reveals the field from the data model. Field's type is List of strings.

I add View Model class containing data class and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IDataErrorInfo` interfaces. View Model contains the `string` property `PropName` and I bind `TextBox.Text` to `PropName` in two way direction. `PropName` setter and getter convert string to `List<string>` and back. They use spaces as delimiters to split the string into the parts. Also, I have validation to check the string and I want it works right after the text is being changed, so I use `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` to validate immediately. How does it work?

Consider an example. My expectation is User types a word then delimiter then a word again and it is converted to `List<string>`. Right after the user adds delimiter someone executes storing the value to the source and the conversion occurs and trims the last delimiter as useless. After that, someone reads property again (I've tried to not call `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` but without success) and the last delimiter is disappeared. If the user inserts delimiter into the word in the middle all works fine.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="PropName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <DataErrorValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

---

```
class DataModel
{
    public List<string> PropName{get;set;}
};

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private DataModel data;
    public string PropName
    {
        get { return data.PropName.Join(' '); }
        set
        { 
            data.PropName = value.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            RaisePropertyChanged();// I can don't call it. It doesn't affect.
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please include sample XAML, model class and view model class?

Comment: @CorentinPane, sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you shouldn't implement a view model to view conversion inside the view model.
For this scenario you should implment a `IValueConverter` (see [Microsoft Docs: Data Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframework-4.8#data-conversion)).

To solve your problem, you have two options: use the default `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `TextBox`, which is `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` or suppress the binding update in case the `TextBox.Text` value ends with a specific seperator.

I recommend to switch back to the `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` value. It doesn't make sense to validate the input for every character. `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` makes perfect sense in scenarios like spellchecking or typing suggestions.

The following example shows how to use proper value conversion and suppress the binding:

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
  private DataModel Data { get; set; }

  private List<string> propName;
  public List<string> PropName
  {
    get => this.Data;
    set
    { 
      this.Data.PropName = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**ListToStringConverter.cs**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(List<string>), typeof(string))]
public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return value is IEnumerable<string> stringCollection 
      ? string.Join(";", stringCollection)
      : Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {";", " "};
    return value is string stringValue && stringValue.LastIndexOfAny(stringSeparators) < stringValue.Length - 1 
      ? stringValue.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList() 
      : Binding.DoNothing;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding Path="PropName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.Converter>
          <ListToStringConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
          <DataErrorValidationRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>
</Window>
```

Comment: What happens if the user leaves TextBox with delimiter as last char? What will PropName equal to?

Comment: I assumed that ending the input with a delimiter is not allowed or at least this delimiter will be ignored. In case you stay with the `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` setting you already have the value up to the ending delimiter storedin your view model: the binding updated _before_ the ignored delimiter and will continue to update with tthe next input _after_  the delimiter. If you use `UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">` you need to trim or drop the last illegal delimiter, which is automatically done when using `string.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` argument.

Comment: Thanks, I got you! Fix the mistake at ListToStringConverter.cs at last two lines where you doubled "else" case and I'll approve it.

Comment: I have a question although, in case I won't use IValueConverter. Why do they call getter after setter in the case where RaisePropertyChanged doesn't be called?

Comment: I fixed the duplicate return. Than you, I didn't realized it.

Comment: I am sorry I think I didn't understand your question's scenario. You convert inside your property getter and setter, right? Now user enters a ';'  character, right? The point is that the binding has already executed. So you entered the setter but return without raising the PropertyChanged event. Because it's a TWoWay binding the binding fetches data after send. Is this answering your question, did I get you right?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. It looks true but I didn't read about this behaviour anywhere. I thought the two way binding fetched data only by PropertyChanged event. I'll appreciate if you give me the link about two-way fetching feature.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota I don't have a link. It's knowledge based on experience. I think I observed this behavior long time ago.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota The behavior makes sense: when you send data back to the source (view model property), then the `set` method of the source property is invoked. But there exists a possibility that the new value will be manipulated/coerced inside this `set` method. To guarantee that source and target are always in sync (`BindingMode.TwoWay`), the binding sends the probably manipulated value immediately back to the target (e.g. `TextBox`) by invoking the `get` method.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota You should be able to validate this behavior by setting up breakpoints in the `get` and `set` methods of the binding's source property.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but WPF doesn't show sensible stack to see the source code. Anyway, thanks for the solution and the information.

Comment: If you want to see internals check [Microsoft Reference Source: BindingExpressionBase](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpressionBase.cs,4ccea34eb067d822) and start with `BindingExpressionBase.IsDirty` or the private `Dirty()` member. Just click on method names to jump to the caller's context.